# Making shapes from user input

Tags: python

The program should get two numbers from the user. The first number is the amount of triangles. The second number is the amount of rows per triangle.

It's based off a square problem we just did which is

```
numRows = input('Please enter the number of rows: ')
numRows = eval(numRows)
numAst  = 1 
for i in range(numRows):
    print(numAst*'*')
    numAst += 1
```

I can not for the life of me figure out how to get it to make triangles though. I know I need some sort of outside loop to restart the inner loop, but I'm not sure how to go about that?

Comment: Looks to me like your "square problem" code generates a triangle. Just put that in an outer loop controlled by the number of them wanted. Nested loops are just indented one level more than the one containing them.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's a little dangerous to use `eval` to cast unsafe user input to an integer, so I changed this to `int` instead.

Second, you just need to make a nested loop with the number of triangles value to repeat the inner loop `X` times.  And of course you need to change your inner loop function to print triangles instead.

Try this and see if you can understand it from the explanation above:

```
numTris = input('Please enter the number of triangles: ')
numTris = int(numTris)
numRows = input('Please enter the number of rows: ')
numRows = int(numRows)
for _ in range(numTris):
    for numAst in range(1, numRows + 1):
        print(numAst * '*')
    print('')
```

Note: the variable `_` is typically used by convention for a value that you don't intend to use.  In this case, we only need it to create the loop but don't use it within the loop.